# duplicate datatable column names

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datable with column names I0,I1,I2 etc. However these aren't actual column names. I store the column names in another table.

I then have a loop to map the actual column names as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt_key.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt_data.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt_key.Rows[i][0].ToString();
}
```

I get the following errors:

> A column named 'Pressure' already belongs to this DataTable.

and

> A column named 'Size' already belongs to this DataTable.

Ultimately I am trying to write this to a xml file:

```
dt_data.WriteXml(filename);
```

This works but I end up the column names I0..I22

There are similar questions to this, but they are trying to make datatables with duplicate columns names. I am just trying to print out a table with duplicate column names. What is a good method to do this?

**Edit:**

I can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt_key.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt_data.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt_key.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + dt_data.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}
```

Comment: Would it be alright if the 2nd 'MVT Pressure' column was named 'MVT Pressure 2'?

Comment: Yes I could do that, but I would prefer not to

Comment: Does the RDBMS you are using support outputting XML from queries (like MS-SQL, Oracle, DB2)? Seems like a lot of steps just to create XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is that there is no way to have duplicate column names using a `DataTable`.  What exactly are you using this XML for?  There are lots of alternate ways to generate XML that give you a lot more fine grained control.

You could manually create your file using an `XmlWriter` object.  [This method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcsse48t.aspx) creates an `XmlWriter` that writes to a file.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt_key.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       if(dt_data.Columns.Contains(dt_key.Rows[i][0].ToString()))             
         dt_data.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt_key.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "  " ;
      else
         dt_data.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt_key.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    }
```

**However adding a same column name is a bad practise,still you could achieve that by adding a space at the end of column name to make it unique.**

Comment: Your code works only for 1 case: if 2 columns are the same then add space, but if 3 or more columns are the same then a crash occurs.

Comment: "               var col = colName;
                while (dtR.Columns.Contains(col)) col += " ";
                dtR.Columns.Add(col); "
But is a bad practise...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make use of the DataColumn.Caption property to store the column display name:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.caption(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can not duplicate Column names by using  `Data Table`.Consider this and find another solution .

If you try to duplicate Column name then it will show an error like that you mentioned.

> A column named 'Pressure' already belongs to this Data Table .

In here you try to duplicate Column name **'Pressure'** that's why that error comes.